# How to Increase Max SQL Connection Pool Size for .Net App

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, connection-pooling

I have a .NET application which sends requests to a large number of databases in parallel and seems to be running out of connections from the pool, leading to timeouts. I'd like to increase the pool size but am confused as to how to do this globally.

I know that I can set Max Pool Size in the connection string as below

```
connectionString="Server=.;database=DBName;Trusted_connection=true;pooling=true;Max Pool Size=200;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

But this seems to be database specific.

1. Is the max pool size specified in the connection string a limit on the number of connections the .Net application can have, or a limit on the number of connections it can have to that specific database?
2. What would happen if some connection strings had an increased limit, and other connection strings had a low limit within the same .net application?
3. How can I increase the number of connections allowed in the pool for my application?

Comment: each different connection string creates a new pool, are you using always the same connection string for each database connection then changing away from the master in code, or are you connecting to each DB with a different connection string?   Are you failing to be able to open DB connections, or are commands timing out?

Comment: how many connections are you using?  Have you tried writing experimental code to open multiple connections, then find out where the limit occurs?  You need to find out what resource it is that is becoming exhausted, and whether it is a SQL server limit or a .net limit.

Comment: Different connection strings for each connection so the max pool size probably isn't the problem. We're getting both connection timeouts and command timeouts.
It's been a difficult one to replicate unfortunately. We're pretty sure the limit lies within .net but it's not consistently reproducable.

Comment: How are you creating multiple processes?  Are you using multiple threads in .net or are you using multiple asynchronous command executions?

Comment: Multiple threads using Task.Run

Comment: What I once did when I found there was a point where adding further concurrent processes made everything slower, was that that I put the processes in class objects with a property saying not_started, running, finished, error and by putting the objects in a list I used  LINQ and a loop such that I only started a process when the number running was < n, that way I could prevent saturation of resources.